# Open calendar with API 14 or lower

Tags: android

I want to open calendar from a widget app, for version API 15 or higher it works with this code:

```
RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.medium_layout);
    Intent calendar = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(
             Intent.ACTION_MAIN, 
             Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALENDAR);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            calendar, 0);

    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.calendar, pendingIntent2);
```

but for versions before 15 it doesn´t work, any help?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official Calendar API before Android 4.0

Comment: If you want to use your calendar data or to add new events you could check this http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can't open calendar for Api lower than than 15.But you can create your custom calender.[click here to see](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-simple-calendar/)

Comment: Ok, I prefer open google calendar in lower versions, thank you very much